# how to check if application was installed earlier or not?

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

Here I have a problem in checking if application was installed on the device before or not.
What actually I am trying to do is.. In my application only one user can register. What I had done is once register I am removing the Register button. The problem is when I uninstall the application and re-install it it gives shows me register button again because the flag was set in my application database. Is there any way by which I can remember that application was installed before and registration is done. So I can hide this button for future install too.

I don't know whether NSUserDefaults will help me to solve this issue or not. Please navigate me to the appropriate tutorial..

Thanks to all

Comment: It is just not possible.

Comment: Nsuserdefault wont gonna help... as it gets removed when application is removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the udid number of the device( which is unique) on your server.. and on each install you can know if that udid number is already on your server then it means that the application is already register.

Happy iCoding...

Answer (score 1):

If an user deletes the application it will delete all the files associated with that application.

What you can do is to create an web service on your server and keep the registered users and device UDID's in some database on your server. When you first start the app check on your server to see the status.